# How to display the index of an array using the vuetify data table?

Tags: arrays, laravel, vue.js, datatables, vuetify.js

I have a response from server which has the array of data passing to my vue instance. I have completed the data table using that array.But all i need to know how can I display the index of my array for serial no.

here i am attaching my component code
My response is ok and table is ok too.I just need to increase a column more and display the index value there.

My array name is customers.

```
<v-data-table
  v-bind:headers="headers"
  v-bind:items="customers"
  v-bind:search="search"
  v-cloak
  >
  <template slot="items" scope="props">
  <td class="text-xs-center">@{{ props.item.id }}</td>
  <td class="text-xs-center">
    <v-edit-dialog
      lazy
      @{{ props.item.name }}
      >
      <v-text-field
        slot="input"
        label="Edit"
        v-model="props.item.name"
        single-line
        counter
        :rules="[max25chars]"
        ></v-text-field>
    </v-edit-dialog>
  </td>
  <td class="text-xs-center">@{{ props.item.email }}</td>
  <td class="text-xs-center">@{{ props.item.email }}</td>
  <td class="text-xs-center">@{{ props.item.created_at }}</td>
  <td class="text-xs-center">
    <v-btn small outline fab class="red--text" @click="showWarning(props.item.id)">
      <v-icon>mdi-account-remove</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
    <v-btn small outline fab class="green--text" @click="showWarning(props.item.id)">
      <v-icon>mdi-account-off</v-icon>
    </v-btn>
  </td>
  </template>
  <template slot="pageText" scope="{ pageStart, pageStop }">
    From @{{ pageStart }} to @{{ pageStop }}
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Comment: Properly formatted code will help us debug your code as it allows others to copy and paste your code more easily.

Comment: ooo ok tnks :) :)

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**EDIT 7/30/19**
As @titou10 mentioned, there is no index field within **Vuetify 2.0**.

After looking around for a bit I was able to achieve this by utilizing the `item.<name>` [slot](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables#api). This slot will return me an `item`. I created an array of IDs based on the object `id` and called `indexOf(item.id)` to get the index position.

Code pen [HERE](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JgNPQd?&editable=true&editors=101).

---

**Vuetify 1.x**

Each one of your props object contains two keys: `item` and `index`. You can access the index for each item by doing `props.index`. Adding a new header is as easy as adding a new item to your headers array.

Here is a codepen as an example. I am changing the first column of the data-table to the index position.

https://codepen.io/potatogopher/pen/eGBpVp

Comment: thank you brother.Googled few times but couldnt find according to my satisfaction.Perfectly works fyn :) :) @nick-rucci

Comment: When you are using pagination, props.index will provide the item index relative to the current showing page. In such a scenario you need to calculate the correct array index using following method     
(currentPagenumber -1 )*pageSize + props.index

Comment: it seems that index is not there anymore in vuetify 2.0...https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables#api

Comment: @titou10 I've updated my answer with the new information that you've shared. Thank you.

Comment: @NickRucci thx for your answer but it looks more like a workaround to me. Too bad they removed this feature in Vuetify v2.x as IMHO getting the index of the row being processed is something that is frequently needed

Comment: Thank you for this answer, i was able to solve use this in vue-tables-2 in a situation where my data is an array of objects.

Comment: It is not a good idea do it as this solution. The fact that you need to map 1 million records until get the right position will be take down the site

Comment: @FernandoTorres Do you have an alternative solution that handles loading 1 million records with the Vuetify 2.0 table?

Answer (score 9):

Another approach that can be used is using computed properties to insert the index to each element in the data. This can be useful if you need to update the table later on as computed properties are updated automatically.

For example, say the item data is stored in `items`.

```js
data() {
  return {
    items: [{
      fruit_name: 'Banana',
      calories: 30
    }, {
      fruit_name: 'Apples',
      calories: 40
    }]
  }
}
```

Here, every element to be itself plus additional attribute, i.e. `index`. Element addition is achieved using [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax#Spread_in_object_literals). All mapped elements are combined into single array using functional-programming style of [`map` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
computed: {
  itemsWithIndex: () {
    return this.items.map(
      (items, index) => ({
        ...items,
        index: index + 1
      }))
  }
}
```

Note: `index: index+1` will make the numbering start from 1.

Then, inside headers data needed for `v-data-table`, you can make reference to `index` item data for numbering.

```js
data() {
  return {
    items: {
      ...
    },
    headers: [{
        text: 'Num',
        value: 'index',
      },
      {
        text: 'Fruit Name',
        value: 'fruit_name',
      },
      {
        text: 'Calories',
        value: 'calories',
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Codepen example: https://codepen.io/72ridwan/pen/NWPMxXp

Answer (score 7):

Super simple , Use indexOf  {{items.indexOf(props)}}

Comment: In vuetify 2.3.13 it's  {{ items.indexOf(props.item) }}

Comment: @PiotrŻak +1) `{{ items.indexOf(item) }}`

Answer (score 7):

```
<v-data-table
  :headers="dessertHeaders"
  :items="desserts"
  single-expand
  :expanded.sync="expanded"
  item-key="name"
  show-expand
  class="elevation-1"
>
  <template v-slot:item.sn="{ index }">
    {{ index + 1 }}
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

Where `sn` is the header you want to replace the index with.

Check this screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Best answer, de structure `index` from the slotted item.

Answer (score 3):

You can use this:

```
{{props.index}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to [this sandbox](https://codepen.io/potatogopher/pen/eGBpVp), I was able to show index in each row using the code below:

```
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="items"
>
  <template slot="item.rank" scope="props">
    {{ props.index + 1 }}
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

where the headers section is like this:

```js
headers: [
  { name: 'rank', value: 'rank' },
  // other headers
]
```

Answer (score 2):

Just need to do this:

```
    <template #item.serialNo="{item}">
    <td >
    {{ArrayName.indexOf(item) + 1}}
    </td>
    </template>
```

ArrayName: the array we use in ':items' of

serialNo: the value to select the column

Answer (score 1):

Easy peasy :)

```
<template>
    <v-data-table
          :headers="headers"
          :items="items"
          sort-by="calories"
          hide-default-footer
          class="elevation-1"
    >

        <template v-slot:item.count="{item, index}">
            {{index+1}}
        </template>

    </v-data-table>
</template>

<script>

export default {
    data: () => ({
    headers: [
      {
            text: "#",
            sortable: false,
            value: "count",
          },]
        })
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Be careful to handle page 2, 3...

@Hosien's answer worked form me, however I needed to modify the index to handle pagination - on subsequent pages the index was always starting from 0 again.

In your data(), define

```js
  pagination: {
    page: 1,
    itemsPerPage: 15
  }
```

... add this for your table:

```html
    <v-data-table
      :items="items"
      :headers="headers"
      :page.sync="pagination.page"
      :itemsPerPage.sync="pagination.itemsPerPage">
```

... and put this in for the index field.

```html
   <!-- remember to populate the count field as per Hosien's example! -->
   <template #[`item.count`]="{ index }">
     {{ (pagination.page - 1) * pagination.itemsPerPage + index + 1}}
   </template>
```