# how to add a column that numbers the table?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js, vuex

I use data-table with vuetify, You can see the final result I want in the image below.
just add a column in the left side.
I use data-table with vuetify, You can see the final result I want in the image below.
just add a column in the left side.

```
<template>
  <v-card>
    <v-card-title>
      <v-text-field
        v-model="search"
        append-icon="mdi-magnify"
        label="Search"
        single-line
        hide-details
      ></v-text-field>
    </v-card-title>
    <v-data-table
      :headers="headers"
      :items="products.records"
      :search="search"
      :loading="isLoading"
    ></v-data-table>
  </v-card>
</template >

<script>
export default {
  name: "products",
  data() {
    return {
      search: "",
      headers: [
        {
          text: "Year",
          align: "start",
          filterable: true,
          value: "fields.year",
        },
        { text: "Item", value: "fields.item" },
        { text: "Element", value: "fields.element" },
        { text: "Value", value: "fields.value" },
        { text: "Unit", value: "fields.unit" },
        { text: "Area Code", value: "fields.area_code" },
        { text: "Area", value: "fields.area" },
      ],
      isLoading:true,
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.$store.dispatch("loadProducts");
  },
  computed: {
    products() {
      return this.$store.state.products;
      
    },
  },
  updated(){
    this.isLoading=false
  }
};
</script>
```

[image: this is the result i want]

Comment: Can't you add a new `header` and set the index there?

Comment: I think it's been answered here. Can you please check?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46380574/how-to-display-the-index-of-an-array-using-the-vuetify-data-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way I can think to do this is with the [`item.<name>`](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/#slots-item.%3Cname%3E) slot which provides the row index which you can then easily display.  For the `<name>` part of `item.<name>` just use a fake column name, e.g. `item.num` since it's not related to anything in your actual items data

```html
<v-data-table
  :headers="headers"
  :items="products.records"
  :search="search"
  :loading="isLoading"
>
  <template v-slot:item.num="{ index }">
    {{ index + 2 }}
  </template>
</v-data-table>
```

2 is added to the index so that the first row displays "2" since according to your image the header should display "1". The header value is set by just adding another object to the header array with `text: '1', value: 'num'`:

```js
headers: [
        { text: '1', value: 'num', sortable: false },
        {
          text: "Year",
          align: "start",
          filterable: true,
          value: "fields.year",
        },
        { text: "Item", value: "fields.item" },
        { text: "Element", value: "fields.element" },
        { text: "Value", value: "fields.value" },
        { text: "Unit", value: "fields.unit" },
        { text: "Area Code", value: "fields.area_code" },
        { text: "Area", value: "fields.area" },
      ]
```

[codesandbox](https://codepen.io/yoduh/pen/gOKoMeM) if you'd like to see a code example.

Comment: I think there would be an issue with this if there are more then 10 items and user goes to page 2 by default table pagination he will still see 1 to 11

Answer (score 0):

You can use following solution in v-for:

```
 <tr v-for="(obj,index) in Object_Name" :key="obj.id">
     <td>
        {{ index+1 }}
     </td>
 </tr>
```